# Toolstrip is flashing - blanking

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vb.net-2010

I use :
 - Windows 7
 - VS2010 SP1
 - Framework 4
 - Winforms
 - MDI Parent
 - StatusStrip

My main form is MDI parent with a StatusStrip that contains 6 StatusLabels.
When the main form is maximised, the tooltips from the StatusStrip start flashing.
It only seems to happen when the form is maximised.
I am thinking if it has to do with the operating system task bar and the space between them.
The code that I use is very simple :

```
 Me.lblServer.ToolTipText = myServer.Name 'lblServer is a StatusLabel
```

I tried also to set the tooltip by myself in lblServer_MouseHover:

```
 ToolTip.SetToolTip(lblServer, myServer.Name)
```

but lblServer is not a control, so it is impossible to do it that way.
Does anyone have an idea how to work around this problem?

Thanks

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/fba8a82f-a2bc-44b4-be7d-026c4332a56f/ chk this

Comment: Tooltip will flash rapidly when you display them in a MouseMove event handler and you position them at the mouse position.  Don't put them there.

Comment: @Nianios - feel like sharing the solution, so other will get helped too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution for the problem is:
Add a ToolTip in your form.
Be sure that property OwnerDrawn=False.
Then add this code in the StatusLabel (lblServer) events:

```
Private Sub lblServer_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblServer.MouseHover
   MainToolTip.Show(myServer.Name, myStatusBar, New Point(lblServer.Bounds.Right, lblServer.Bounds.Top - 10))
End Sub
Private Sub lblItems_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblServer.MouseLeave
    ' Hide the tooltips in the StatusStrip
    MainToolTip.Hide(myStatusBar)
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help.